# How to merge two plots in Mathematica 8.0 in a column and then save the figure as a single pdf file?

Tags: plotting, graphics, pdf-format

I have defined two plots and then want to merge them into one so that I can save the figure as a pdf file into my computer. Here is MWE where I would like to merge two plots into one:

```
plot1 = LogPlot[...];
plot2 = LogPlot[...];
GraphicsColumn[{plot1, plot2}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

I can successfully plot 1 and 2 independently and save them as two separate pdf files. Both plots have accompanying legends. However, after merging them into one figure, I do not know how to save it as a pdf file as I am not given any such option by right-clicking on the figure. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

---

Here is the plot I am getting from `Grid` command:[image]

Comment: Export["plot.pdf",Grid[{{plot1},{plot2}}]]. If you want to use click, then select the full figure and go to File>Save Selection As and then save it as a pdf.

Comment: Hi Sumit, thanks. The first code produces some file that is very very messed up that you cannot even realize anything from it. And the second one just takes forever to be saved. I think I need to write my plots completely so that help may be faster.

Comment: can you show the image/screenshot of what you are getting with `Grid[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a kick --- sunday --- answer

```
 p1 := Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}]
 p2 := Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 1}]
 GraphicsGrid[{{p1}, {p2}}]
 Export["Where you want\\name of the file", pasted GraphicsGrid]
```

You may copy the GraphicsGrid on clicking on the vertical bar

Comment: Yes. copying from vertical bar worked. Thanks,

Comment: What is the format of "Where you want\\name of the file" if it's named "myplot" and it is in my "desktop" under "U of A" user?

Comment: Sorry I have not seen the add earlier.  I do not know on what system you work. I work on windows so Where ou whant is the path where you want to save your file and name of the file to remember that you may chose the name and the format  --- jpg, png, eps...